# AdSense GDPR consent message not showing

Tags: adsense, gdprconsentform, fundingchoices, ccpa

I have been trying to implement the AdSense GDPC consent message for a few days. I have completed the implementation, but the GDPR message is not showing. I tried logging `tcData` after implementing the `__tcfapi` callback, and the result was:

From India

```
cmpId: 300
cmpStatus: "loaded"
cmpVersion: 2
eventStatus: null
gdprApplies: false
listenerId: 1
tcfPolicyVersion: 2
```

From Netherlands via VPN

```
cmpId: 300
cmpStatus: "loaded"
cmpVersion: 2
eventStatus: null
gdprApplies: true
listenerId: 0
tcfPolicyVersion: 2
```

I also tried testing instructions from [Site message testing instructions and parameters](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10924669?hl=en#zippy=%2Csite-message-testing-instructions-and-parameters), and the result was:

- Ad blocking recovery message is showing
- CCPA message not showing without clicking "Do Not Sell My Data"
- GDPR message not showing at all

Thanks